iOS Notification is permanently denied - can't find in settings for manual enabling
I implemented push notification in iOS and android, using APN Apple Push notification and firebase respectively. In iOS first request for notification is from native side (appDelegate/swift code) and if that is denied I'm again requesting for notification permission using permission_handler. But when I denied multiple times the flutter code can't request for permission but from native code it's showing the permission dialogue. And also in flutter side it showing PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied. And when I am checking settings to enable manually option for notification is not showing in setting.
Permission requesting code is given below,
await Permission.notification.isDenied.then((value) async {
      if (value) {
        var req = await Permission.notification.request();
        print($req);
      }
    });

swift code is,
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
            if granted {
                print("Notification permission allowed.")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            } else {
                print("Permission for push notifications denied.")
            }
        }


expecting a solution for notification option in settings app or permission request dialogue even after permission denied.

There is a section in the permission_handler documentation, where it mentions how to approach permanently denied permissions.
Instructions

You can also open the app settings:

if (await Permission.speech.isPermanentlyDenied) {
  // The user opted to never again see the permission request dialog for this
  // app. The only way to change the permission's status now is to let the
  // user manually enables it in the system settings.
  openAppSettings();
}

How to apply this for you
In your case you would simply need to replace speech with notification and you would be good to go:
if (await Permission.notification.isPermanentlyDenied) {
  openAppSettings();
}


I used openAppSettings(); but it only opens the settings of the correspond app. In that settings there is no option for notifications.

Then you might not have done the setup of the permission correctly. Have you tried following the setup steps listed here (under iOS): https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler#setup

See, the problem is when permission is denied there is no option to enable it manually in settings. If permission is accepted first time then there will be option for manually enable or disable notification permission.
